# Wrong function context

Tags: javascript

I would expect a function's context (`this`) to be the same as its parent/scope. Should it not be so?

Check the example under, I would expect `_context` to get the value of *Object* `{foo: "bar"}`, but instead I get `window` object.

Where is my logic cheating me?

```
var context = {
    foo: 'bar'
};
var _context;
var fn = (function () {

    console.log(this); // Object {foo: "bar"}
    function foo() {
        _context = this;
    }
    foo();
}.bind(context))();

console.log(_context); // window?! why?
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1nz4dda3/

Comment: Every function call sets `this`. `this` is effectively a function parameter.

Comment: Function `foo` has it's own scope, and no defined `this` value, so `this` becomes the global.

Comment: Every function block has its own scope. In your example `function foo()` has window scope as you have not binded any scope for that as you did for `fn`. Try http://jsfiddle.net/1nz4dda3/2/

Comment: So any function without `.bind(differentContext)` runs with `window` context?

Comment: @Rikard, value for `this` inside function depends on how function was call

Comment: If you want a function that follows the same `this` as its outer scope, use ES6 Arrow functions. `var ar = (arg1, arg2) => { var thing; return thing; }`

Comment: A function's *this* isn't "context". Each function has an execution context, which includes all it's variables, parameters and scope chain. Its *this* parameter is just one aspect of that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function's *this* is set by how it's called, or by *bind*. ECMAScript 2015 arrow functions get their *this* from the surrounding execution context.

The *this* value isn't "context", it just one parameter of a function's execution context.

When you do:

```
var fn = (function () {
  ...
}.bind(context))();
```

you are binding the object *context* to the IIFE's *this*. However, when you call:

```
foo();
```

you haven't set its *this* parameter, so it will default to the global object (window in a browser). In strict mode, it will be undefined. It does not matter where you call *foo* from, it's how you call it that sets its *this*.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function plainly in the `window` context by calling `foo()`. In JS `this` refers to the calling context and it doesn't matter where any function is written inside.

Here is a good article about JS method context.

http://helephant.com/2009/11/29/javascript-method-context/

Comment: this call in _window_ context only if before somewhere not used `"use strict"`

Comment: *foo* is being called in the IIFE's context (i.e. from within its execution context). *foo*'s *this* is set to the global object because it's not set to anything else in the call.